# Home B&W developing - very dark areas gone white

Tags: developing, black-and-white, fixer

Ilford FP4 125, developed in a Paterson tank with Ilfosol 3 1+14 for 7.5 minutes @20C, Ilfostop,  Ilford Rapid fixer. As far as I can tell, exactly as required ... no intentional liberties or experiments were involved.

But it looks like what should be solid black has been washed out ... can anyone kindly point me towards the processing error I've made here, and whether there is a technical term for it?

(I'm not saying that this effect is not 100% groovy and artistic mind you)

[image]
[image]

Edit: New film, same process but fresh fixer ... so I think I'm going to call this a fixing problem for now. I'll dip the bad 'uns in fresh fixer and see if it does anything to them also.

[image]

Comment: How was it agitated?

Comment: A few brisk twirls with the tank's agitation stick initially (plus a couple of bench taps), then on every minute a single, gentle invert-and-back-again of the tank (plus a couple of bench taps).

Comment: Same for the fixing btw.

Comment: Have you made prints from the negatives or have you just scanned them? If you have scanned them, are you sure that you have disabled any infra-red dust removal functionality in your scanner and/or scanner software?

Comment: Scanned ... yes I disabled everything and did a pretty vanilla scan. Scanner fault was also on my mind, but from directly examining the images these look to be accurate. Thanks.

Comment: Might be useful to post the negatives.

Comment: Yes, perhaps it would help if you post a regular photo of the negatives. Do you have enough experience with B&W development to judge if the negatives look 'normal'? How did you dillute the fix? Are you aware of any light leaks in your camera, which could explain the shades around the performation holes along the bottom of the second image? If not, whatever happened there may be related to the other problem.

Comment: Good points - what I mean is that by looking at the negatives themselves i see the negative pattern of the scanned images, but I'll see if I can just take a decent photo.

Comment: I've just shot off another 36 on FP4, and I've run it through the same development except with a fresh batch of fixer and more agitation during fixing. Currently drying, so i'll scan some of those and see how they look.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For me this looks like [pseudo-solarisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solarization_(photography)). Also known as [Sabattier effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sabattier_effect). This can happen when film or photo paper are exposed to light after the start of development. It can be counted as artistic effect, but its very hard to be managed (when and how much light to expose film or paper)

Comment: Gosh, it does! But I wonder how that could have happened ... do you think that could be from a problem with the fixing?

Comment: @DavidAldridge, I do not have deep knowledge in chemistry, but AFAIK this effect is caused by light.

Comment: It could also be normal solarisation, which happens if the film is overexposed by a large amount.

Comment: @jpa, IMHO if the film is overexposed before develop it will be entirely blowout

Comment: @RomeoNinov That depends completely on the difference in brightness between the sky and the trees. Normally solarisation happens when sun ends up in the image, but if this was in a dark forest with long exposure, it could happen with the sky also.

Comment: I am not sure if this explanation is correct. It is very difficult to achieve the sabattier effect even if you try to use it on purpose. I can hardly imagine how a random mistake or error during film processing may cause the effect to appear.

Comment: Thanks @jpa - I think that's unlikely in this case as the shutter speeds were all pretty quick (this was just some test shots on an Olympus XA handheld)

Answer (score 4):

Throw it back in the fixer and see if that helps. Looks like it isn't fixed fully to me.

Comment: Yeah ... I'm not sure if they're restorable as decent images. Maybe for test purposes I'll just leave them out in the light for a bit and see if the images change any more.

Comment: Well, that dripping look on the bottom of the second image often is the result I get when I have under fixed (or not enough agitation). If the trees should be black, that means little to no light hit that part of the film. Developer won't do anything but the fixer will take that area away completely. So it makes sense that the actual white areas look fine (since they didn't need to be fixed as much). It can't hurt to toss it in some fixer for a few minutes.

Comment: Yeah, the foreground foliage and trees in the 2nd image should be very dark. I'll give one of the negatives a dip in fresh fixer and see how she comes out.

Comment: @DavidAldridge Did you fix (pun intended) the problem with fresh fixer?

Comment: Sorry Kevin, I didn't. Work got ahead of my last week, and I think the moment might have passed.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this happen years ago when printing from non-solarized negatives.  The resulting print had metallic silver in the some of the border areas where the tone reverses.  My experience was decades ago in high school photo class, but if memory serves, the issue arose because there was something funny about the developer.

- It's hard to tell from your images above -- are any of the gray areas actually metallic?
- Is there any chance your batch of developer was old?

Comment: Thanks Eiríkr - the developer was fresh from the bottle, which is itself fairly new. It was mixed 1+14 for single use.